# resize an image stored in a folder

Tags: vba, powerpoint, image-resizing

I want to take an image from a folder resize it and store it in the same location with the same name. I saw a lot of examples of how to take an image, resize it and put it inside powerpoint slide but I just want to store it in a folder and not in the presentation. Is that possible?

Comment: you could run it with VBA but resizing would be done by `PowerPoint engine` and than your picture would be `Export` as new jpg picture. I thing it would decrease quality of the image as PP is not software designed for that purpose. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't care a lot about decreasing the quality because the image will be so small and it is not going to notice a lot... But yes it could be a solution. Can you tell me the steps I can follow to make it? Thanks!!

Comment: 1. use `Dir` function to get list of picture files in folder, 2. import each file to your presentation using `Shapes.AddPicture` method, 3.Resize it, 4. Export picture using `Shape().Export` method... it will work as you need.

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while but it was what I needed. It is also important to say that after export it you have to delete it otherwise it will be in the slide.

Answer (score 0):

Use Imagejpeg.

This works to resize a jpeg.  It was written to take $content as a feed from a database - just replace with fread() of the iamge you wish to resize.

```
$newheight=floor($newheight);
$newwidth=floor($newwidth); 
$image=imagecreatefromstring($content);
$newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($newimage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight,$row['width'], $row['height']);
imagejpeg($newimage,$filetosaveto);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I want to do it using VBA